# Flask SQLAlchemy duplicates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I don't understand much about this issue and am trying to figure out how I can get rid of duplicates in my tables.

I use sqlite ( app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f"sqlite:///{DATABASE_PATH}" )

I have a table of couriers, and a table of regions in which couriers work.
I also have a table that links the courier id and the region id.

Here some code:

```py
couriers_regions_relationship = db.Table(
    "couriers_regions",
    db.Column("courier_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("couriers.id")),
    db.Column("region_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("regions.id")),
)
class Couriers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "couriers"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    regions = db.relationship("Regions", secondary=couriers_regions_relationship, lazy='dynamic')
    ...

class Regions(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "regions"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    region = db.Column(db.Integer)
    ...
```

When I create a table and add couriers to it like this:

```py
regions = [123, 77, 103]

new_courier = Couriers()
for region in regions:
    new_courier.regions.append(Regions(region=region))
db.session.add(new_courier)
db.session.commit()
...
regions = [123, 77, 103]
other_courier = Couriers()
for region in regions:
    other_courier.regions.append(Regions(region=region))
db.session.add(new_courier)
db.session.commit()
...
```

I get the following tables:

```
couriers:
id | ...
---|-----
1  | ...
2  | ...

regions:
id | region | ...
---|--------|-----
1  | 123    | ...
2  | 77     | ...
3  | 103    | ...
4  | 123    | ...
5  | 77     | ...
6  | 103    | ...

couriers_regions:
courier_id | region_id
-----------|-----------
1          | 1
1          | 2
1          | 3
2          | 4 
2          | 5 
2          | 6
```

As you can see the data in the table "regions" is duplicated.

What I want to get:

```
couriers:
id | ...
---|-----
1  | ...
2  | ...

regions:
id | region | ...
---|--------|-----
1  | 123    | ...
2  | 77     | ...
3  | 103    | ...

couriers_regions:
courier_id | region_id
-----------|-----------
1          | 1
1          | 2
1          | 3
2          | 1 
2          | 2 
2          | 3
```

I read the relationship documentation in sqlalchemy docs and flask_sqlalchemy docs. Cannot find anything about it there.
I also tried setting flags "unique=True" and "primary_key=True" but it doesn't help.

P.S.

- duplicated regions are absolutely identical
- Of course, I can view the table myself and search for or create the regions I need, links for them, but I want to find a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make a new instance of a `Region` it will be given a new database identity if possible.

Both, here:

```py
for region in regions:
    new_courier.regions.append(Regions(region=region))
```

and here:

```py
for region in regions:
    other_courier.regions.append(Regions(region=region))
```

... you are constructing *new* `Region` instances: `Region(region=region)`.

Instead, construct a collection of `Region` instances, and then assign them to the `Courier` instances:

```py
regions = [Region(region=r) for r in [123, 77, 103]]
```

Then:

```py
new_courier = Couriers(regions=regions)
other_courier = Couriers(regions=regions)
```

In addition, databases provide tools to protect against the sort of data corruption that you are trying to avoid.

You can force `Regions.region` to always be unique by either creating a unique index on the column:

```py
class Regions(db.Model):
    ...
    region = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
```

Or, given that the region number is a unique integer itself, you could make it the primary key:

```py
class Region:
    # You could still call this column `region` but `Region.region` is redundant naming, `Region.id` sounds better to me!
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)

regions = [Region(id=r) for r in [123, 77, 103]]
```

By enforcing uniqueness of the regions at the database layer, it protects you from writing erroneous code that unintentionally creates duplicate region records.

Comment: The problem is that regions cannot be stored in a single python variable. And also, if a courier with regions [123, 77, 99] appears, only region 99 should be added to the region table, and the relationships with all of them will be created automatically

Comment: On your second point, you would issue a query for the existing regions first, e.g., `db.session.query(Regions).all()`, will give you the objects for regions 127, 77 and any other regions that exist in the table already. You would then only have to create a new region for 99. I'm not sure what you mean by "regions cannot be stored in a single python variable". I'm afraid that if you don't include all of the necessary information in your question, you'll get answers incomplete to your needs.

Comment: Irrespective of all that, the point stands that if you want to avoid having duplicates in your tables, you don't allow them in the first place, which my answer demonstrates for you.

Comment: Uh-huh, thanks, just every time I add a new region, I check whether it exists in the table, if so, I take it, otherwise I create a new one